# How to store a timestamp with UTC timezone offset in Java 6 without modifying anything?

Tags: oracle, utc, java-6, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm terribly sorry if this had been asked before, I've tried searching for something that answers my questions but could find none.

The issue is this:
Let's say I have a string that looks like this -> 2017-01-05-04:44:43-06:00 (format being yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss+/-UTC)
Now my goal is to store it as it is in the Oracle database including the offset (as I understand I need to define the column as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE).

So how do I go about capturing the timestamp with the offset into a Java date and time object? I'm not looking to convert the times to UTC, I just want to store it as is and persist that into DB.

Please note that we are on Java 6 so I cannot use java.time package, neither can I use Joda Time. So any solution outside of these would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need to use the date/time in Java, or are you only passing it through to the database - in which case you can pass the string and convert it in the DB?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yea that would be my last resort. But currently there is already a lot of code around this field being defined as a Date in Java, and I was looking for a solution that will avoid doing a lot of code refactor if I convert this to String now. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## java.time

See the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project for a back-port of much of the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) functionality to Java 6 and 7 (java.time is built into Java 8 and later). The API nearly matches so that when you eventually migrate to Java 8 or later, you’ll need do little more than change your `import` statements.

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode though actively maintained. The sponsors advise moving to the java.time classes.

### ISO 8601

Replace that hyphen in the middle of your input string with a `T` to comply with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes for parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-01-05T04:44:43-06:00" );
```

### Search Stack Overflow

> I'm terribly sorry if this had been asked before

Yes, your questions are all duplicates. Please search Stack Overflow for existing answers to all your issues:

- backport of java.time, ThreeTen-Backport
- Parsing strings containing an offset-from-UTC, OffsetDateTime class
- exchanging date-time data with databases and Oracle in particular, JDBC 4.2 for directly exchanging java.time objects, or else calling new methods added to the old classes for converting to/from java.time to `java.sql.Timestamp`, or else on pre-Java-8 convert to `Timestamp` by count-from-epoch numbers.
- Learning just how bad the old legacy date-time classes are, and you absolutely should go to the bother of adding the java.time backport library to your project.

Tip: Do not search from within Stack Overflow website. Their search engine is biased towards Questions while you want to search within Answers. Use `site:stackoverflow.com` in DuckDuckGo, Google, or Bing.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).